# SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I tested this javascript in Chrome's Javascript console and it returned `SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`.

I got this code from a tutorial and was just testing Chrome's console so i expected it to work, unless I'm using the console wrong?

#### Code:

```
var visitorName = "Chuck";
var myOldString = "Hello username. I hope you enjoy your stay username.";
var myNewString = myOldString.replace ("username," visitorName);

document.write("Old String = " + myOldString);
document.write("<br/>New string = " + myNewString);
```

#### Output:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Same error for a different reason  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72127339/getting-this-error-on-running-js-using-node-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-i

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The comma got eaten by the quotes!

This part:

```
("username," visitorName);
```

Should be this:

```
("username", visitorName);
```

---

*Aside*: For pasting code into the console, you can paste them in one line at a time to help you pinpoint where things went wrong ;-)

Comment: It is also a good idea to use some kind of hinter or an IDE that has syntax validation.

Comment: In my case it was the change of API version, I changed from x.7 to x.8 and it worked. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
 var myNewString = myOldString.replace ("username," visitorName);
```

with

```
 var myNewString = myOldString.replace("username", visitorName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error `Unexpected identifier` because of a missing semi-colon `;` at the end of a line. Anyone wandering here for other than above-mentioned solutions, This might also be the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as below

```
<script language="javascript">
var visitorName = 'Chuck';
var myOldString = 'Hello username. I hope you enjoy your stay username.';
```

var myNewString = **myOldString.replace('username', visitorName);**

```
document.write('Old String = ' + myOldString);
document.write('<br/>New string = ' + myNewString);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6xc4/23/

Comment: You really should point out the problem. The OP didn't notice the comma on his/her own code, and isn't likely to spot the change. From a quick look, it looks like you're suggesting to use single quoted string instead of double quoted, which can be confusing - they are the same in JavaScript, but not in all languages (PHP, for one).

Comment: I tried to place myOldString.replace('username', visitorName); in bold but some how if you are placing your code in code section it didn't output it bold.

Comment: You can still edit your answer, of course. (Code's already bolded on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

copy this line and replace in your project

```
var myNewString = myOldString.replace ("username", visitorName);
```

there is a simple problem with coma (,)

Answer (score 0):

I got **SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error, for invalid order between **async** and **static**, static must come first.

```
//Invalid
async static methodName() {

}

//Valid
static async methodName() {

}
```