# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, function

hello im am getting JS error :

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cur_level = 1;
var ids_arr = new Array(<?php echo $max_level?>);
var im_here = new Array(<?php echo $max_level?>);
ids_arr[0] = 1;
im_here[0] = "|";
function displayData(id, level, used, title)
{
if(used){
    choice = document.getElementById('divv'+id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = choice;

} else {
    document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = ' No lerning paths to show.';
    updateLinksDiv(id, level, title);

  }
}

function updateLinksDiv(id, level, title)
{
var links_div_info = document.getElementById('links_parent_'+id);
var tmpHTML = '';
var here = '';

for(i=0;i<level;i++){
    here+= '->'+im_here[i];
    links_div_info = document.getElementById('links_parent_'+ids_arr[i]);
    tmpHTML += '<div id="divl_'+links_div_info.id+'">'+links_div_info.innerHTML+'</div>';
}
links_div_info = document.getElementById('links_parent_'+id);
tmpHTML += '<div id="divl_'+links_div_info.id+'">'+links_div_info.innerHTML+'</div>';

document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = tmpHTML;
ids_arr[i] = id;
im_here[i] = title;
}

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=updateLinksDiv(1 , 0 , "|" ) ;
</script>
```

the functions are suppose to create an "expanding" that opens up with levels and everything was working fine untill i added the "title" and i started getting the error.
the error points me to the last  and i just cant find the error... 
i try to call displayData like this

```
onclick="displayData('.$cat->id.','.$cat->level.',0,'.$cat->title.')"
```

any suggestions for what i'm not seeing.?

thank you

Comment: You have a JavaScript error, please show us the JavaScript and not some PHP that will generate JavaScript.

Comment: Also tell us which line triggers the error.

Comment: As a side note, you should not use the `onxxx` attributes. Instead, bind the events to the elements after the page has loaded - this is called [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Similarily, using `innerHtml` is a receipe for [XSS injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). I strongly recommend using jQuery or a similar library.

Comment: the links the php creats are   displayData(26,1,0,כיתה ג)    and i get the error in the last </script> thats where it points me to...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000114/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chromes-javascript-console)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your comment you say that `displayData(26,1,0,כיתה ג)` is generated. This explains the symptoms, as here the last parameter contains a space in addition to Hebrew letters, so the JavaScript intepreter sees it as two identifiers separated by a space, and the identifiers are probably undefined. Google Chrome gives the error message you describe, whereas Firefox and IE say, more enigmatically, “missing ) after argument list.”

Apparently the generated code is supposed to have the last parameter in quotation marks, i.e. 'כיתה ג'. You need to modify the generation to contain them.

Comment: Check the console in a different browser, Brilliant!