# npm install github gives unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have a github repo in which I'm trying to install [Clockwork SMS](https://www.clockworksms.com/) via npm. However, when I checked the console, it displays a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error. Website can be found here: https://refath.github.io/Niva/.

In summary, what I'm attempting to do is send a message to a phone via Clockwork, but when I attempt to `$ npm install https://github.com/mediaburst/node-clockwork`, the console displays the error: "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**", as shown below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at README in github repo of clockwork https://github.com/mediaburst/node-clockwork/blob/master/README.md you are probably typing the wrong command. Have you tried as described in README: npm install clockwork ?

Also you should give a look here [SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000114/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chromes-javascript-console) and then give a little bit look to your code.