# JS file not loading on IE, works on Chrome in Joomla Seblod

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, joomla

I have added JS as a field on Joomla Seblod, which calls a JS file in my file system **my_profile.js** as follows-

```
jQuery.getScript("/components/com_msp/js/my_profile.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log('inside success in seblod');
    main();
}).fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log('JS failed in seblod..');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqxhr));
    console.log( "Error:" + settings + ' : ' + exception );
});
```

On Chrome, the JS is called correctly and all the code works (I also get `inside success in seblod` message on the Inspect console), but on IE I get this on the console-

```
The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.
JS failed in seblod..
Error:parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier
```

The code inside the files and everything is the same. Till yesterday I could see the changes on IE as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier` was actually causing issues with the JS code on IE. I had to do a line by line debug and finally found 2 instances in the code that was causing this-

1. I was using this to loop through an object- `for(const [serial, dates] of Object.entries(data)) {`. Had to replace this with a simpler **for...in** loop like- `for (var serial in data){ if (data.hasOwnProperty(serial)) {`
2. I'm using **sweetalert** in my script and a `.then((result) => {` inside it, and on some digging I found that IE doesn't take the arrow operators. So instead of that I used a `queue` on sweetalert actions and basically did the same steps but without the arrow operator.

Answer (score 1):

> parsererror : SyntaxError: Expected identifier

As for this error, it means you are using something other than an identifier in a context where one was required. An identifier can be:

- a variable,
- a property,
- an array,
- or a function name.

Please check your JS script, and change the identifier expression.

You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000114/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chromes-javascript-console).

Comment: It was exactly this issue causing the problem. The links helped a lot. It took me through a debugging hell as it wasn't specified anywhere what exactly was causing it. Thanks for pointing this out.