# Getting this error on running js using node : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, syntax-error

The below code works fine in browser but when I try to run via node (in command prompt), it give error : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Please find the screenshot attached for an error.

```js
//index.js

// This is my first JS code
console.log('Hello World');
```

```html
//index.html 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>  
    <script src="index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: are you in the right folder? what is result of ```dir``` command in cmd

Comment: Yes, the below is the result of dir

05-05-2022  17:12    <DIR>          .
05-05-2022  17:01    <DIR>          ..
05-05-2022  18:12               335 index.html
05-05-2022  18:12                72 index.js
2 File(s)            407 bytes
2 Dir(s)  343,672,176,640 bytes free

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I started a node then ran below commands:

```js
node
node index.js
```

All I had to do is just go to the directory and run this single command >>
node index.js