# I'm getting ""Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"" while trying to console the book object the problem is in the onclick="alertCLick(book)"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml

```js
  const dataContainer = document.querySelector('.elements')
    
    data.map((book) => dataContainer.innerHTML += 
    `<div class='book' onclick="alertClick(${book})">${book.name}</div>`
    )
    
    const alertClick = (book) => {
        console.log(book)
    }
```

Comment: You need quotes in the parentheses in the onclick call to `alertClick()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000114/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chromes-javascript-console)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by `@Pointy` in comments you need quotes in the parentheses in the `onclick` event handler!

```js
const dataContainer = document.querySelector('.elements')
data = ['Clean Code', 'The C programming language']
data.map((book) => dataContainer.innerHTML +=
  `<div class='book' onclick="alertClick('${book}')">${book}</div>`
)

const alertClick = (book) => {
  console.log(book)
}
```

```html
<div class='elements'/>
```

Comment: It's generally best not to answer "simple typographical error" questions. Instead, flag or vote to close them as such. Questions like these are not likely to be of any help to anyone in the future and therefor just take up unnecessary space on SO.